# WPF self-validating control

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, custom-controls

I have to build a custom control. Simple TextBox with built-in validation which I can use in different parts of my app.
I did it this way:

1. I created new custom control (call it ValidTextBox) derived directly from TextBox;
2. It has its viewmodel (ValidTextBoxVM) with simple validation logic.
3. The Text property of the control is binded to Number property of the viewmodel.

ValidTextBoxVM code:

```
public class ValidTextBoxVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    #region INotifyPropertyChange implementation

    private String _number;
    public String Number 
    {
      get { return _number; }
      set 
      {
        if (_number != value)
        {
          Validate(value);
          _number = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("Number");
        }
      }
    }

    private void Validate(string number)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(number) && number.Length > 10)
      {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Number too long.");
      }
    }
  }
```

ValidTextBox.xaml code:

```
<TextBox x:Class="WpfApplication1.ValidTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Text="{Binding Number, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
    <TextBox.DataContext>
        <vm:ValidTextBoxVM/>
    </TextBox.DataContext>
</TextBox>
```

I put my control on MainWindow and it worked perfectly. While losting focus - ViewModel raised the exception if validation process didn't pass - that's OK (code below).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ctrl:ValidTextBox Margin="5" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The situation changed when I use seperate viewmodel for my MainWindow (MainWindowVM) and bind Text property of my control with field (MainNumber) in a MainWindowVM.
It's hidden my previous binding and validation has stopped to work (code below).

```
<StackPanel>
    <ctrl:ValidTextBox Text="{Binding MainNumber, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Margin="5" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there any pattern that makes creating of self-validating controls possible. I found many solutions but with validation process outside the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is setting `DataContext` on your `TextBox`.  This means that when you write:

```
<ctrl:ValidTextBox Text="{Binding MainNumber
```

... the framework will attempt to resolve "MainNumber" on the `ctrl:ValidTextBox` object, which is the object's DataContext.  (It's counter-intuitive, but that is how it works -- you should be able to see a binding error along the lines of "cannot find property "MainNumber" on the object "ValidTextBox", if you check the Visual Studio "Output" window.)

---

I have found that using control-specific view models is tricky in general, and leads to complications.  I suggest avoiding that approach where possible.  In this case, why not just extend `TextBox` and add a validation handler to the `LostFocus` event?

```
public class ValidTextBox : TextBox
{
    public ValidTextBox()
    {
        LostFocus += ValidTextBox_LostFocus;
    }

    void ValidTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO validate
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. My solution generates an error in "Output" window. But I validate on exceptions and handling validation in event handler (without any binding) makes throwing exceptions a bad solution = "unhandled exception" error. Is there any way to inform a hosting form about validation failure?